# Multiple Definition на C++ не даёт покоя

Tags: c++, компиляция, линковка

Делаю небольшой проект в Qt Creator. Есть три файла и 2 из них конфликтуют между собой и линковщику становится плохо - выдает мне Multiple Definition.

Вот код:

Game.h:

```
#pragma once

#include <iostream>
#include <X11/Xlib.h> // Нужное подключение

// Тут небольшой пропуск...

using namespace std;

// Инициализация функций
void menu(); // Для меню
void start(); // Для инициализации
void customize(); // Для отдельной кастомизации

// Переменные из Xlib для определения ширины и высоты монитора
Display *d;
Screen *s;

// Если что все структуры описаны, и описаны правильно
struct main_character character;
vector<struct location*> locations;
struct save _save;

// И остальное...
```

Game.cpp:

```
#include "Game.h"

void start()
{
    d = XOpenDisplay(NULL);
    s = DefaultScreenOfDisplay(d);

  // С остальным проблем нет
}

void menu()
{
    // Тут проблем нет..
}

void customize()
{
   character.life = bool;
   character.health = 100;
   // И остальное настраивание
}
```

main.cpp

```
#include "Game.h" // Просто подключаю
   
int main()
{
       start(); // Просто начинаю программу
}
```

Вообщем за такое мне линковщик сказал, что с переменными d, s, character, location, _save (притом, что 2 последних я даже не использовал) произошел Multiple Definition, first define here. Я подумал-подумал и добавил к ним extern

Линковщик таких финтов не понял, и поэтому выдал мне что в функции start() у меня undefined reference to 'd' и to 's', а в customize у меня undefined reference to 'character' (скорее всего если я буду использовать location и _save, то мне тоже влетит, а так пока что норм).
Вообщем я хз почему так, но скорее всего, я криво подключил файлы, хотя всё вроде логично: Game.cpp(описание функций) -> Game.h <- main.cpp

p.s.: если в main.cpp подключить Game.cpp, то всё равно не запустится(

Comment: ну и зачем вам понадобились переменные в хидере?

Comment: объявить их в хидере, а затем использовать в других файлах, притом чтобы присвоить им значения в .cpp файле. Или так лучше не делать?

Comment: @Чичавек, тогда у вас в каждом `.cpp` файле будут разные переменные.

Comment: А если я их extern сделаю? Так же на C можно и на C++ вроде тоже

Comment: @Чичавек вам не рассказывали о вреде глобальных переменных?

Comment: @AndrejLevkovitch бывало, но это надо освежить. Я вас вроде понимаю, мол в Game.cpp будут те же переменные, а вот в других *.cpp будут уже другие, но с тем же именем. Вы это имели ввиду?

Comment: @Чичавек, да. Чтобы тот, к кому вы обращаетесь получил уведомление напишите `@` перед его ником.

Answer (score 3):

Вот такие вещи -

```
Display *d;
Screen *s;
```

надо в заголовочных файлах делать либо `inline` (в последних версиях С++), либо

```
extern Display *d;
extern Screen *s;
```

а затем определять их в .cpp-файле.

Так, как у вас - в каждом .cpp-файле имеются переменные с одинаковыми именами - то самое множественное определение...

Да, на всякий случай - если вам предложат написать вместо `extern` - `static`, ошибки компиляции не будет, но переменная в одном .cpp-файле не будет иметь никакого отношения к той же переменной в другом - это будут разные переменные, несмотря на одинаковое имя.

Comment: ну я так то и добавил extern, и написал про это в вопросе, но линковщик все равно выдал ошибку

Comment: @Чичавек, вам нужно в `.h` файле сделать эти переменные `extern`, а потом в каком-нибудь `.cpp` файле определить их **не** как `extern`.

Comment: прежде чем рассказывать все это ему следовало бы напомнить об опасности глобальных переменных. Ему 100% не нужны эти глобальные переменные, просто не привык передовать переменные как аргументы функций (или т.п.) вот и использует глобальные переменные

Comment: @AndrejLevkovitch хорошо, я положусь на ваш опыт

Answer (score 1):

Почему нельзя организовать переменные и методы в рамках одного класса. Зачем этот глобализм?

```
Game.h

    #pragma once
    
    #include <iostream>
    #include <X11/Xlib.h> // Нужное подключение
    
    // Тут небольшой пропуск...
    
    using namespace std;
    class game
    {
    public:
    // Инициализация функций
    void menu(); // Для меню
    void start(); // Для инициализации
    void customize(); // Для отдельной кастомизации
    private:
    // Переменные из Xlib для определения ширины и высоты монитора
    Display *d;
    Screen *s;
    
    // Если что все структуры описаны, и описаны правильно
    struct main_character character;
    vector<struct location*> locations;
    struct save _save;
    
    // И остальное...
    }

Game.cpp
#include "game.h"

void game::start()
{
    d = XOpenDisplay(NULL);
    s = DefaultScreenOfDisplay(d);

  // С остальным проблем нет
}

void game::menu()
{
    // Тут проблем нет..
}

void game::customize()
{
   character.life = bool;
   character.health = 100;
   // И остальное настраивание
}
```

Ну а в main создать экземпляр и вызвать метод start